# What is the difference between mocking and simulating virtual services?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, integration-testing

I have been looking at [CodeSV](http://codesv.io/), a free Java library which enables to set up virtual services in unit testing. I do not quite understand the difference between that and mocking. According to CodeSV's authors their library can achieve more than mocking. What would be the advantages of one approach against another?

Comment: From their docs: http://codesv.io/index.php/2017/10/30/when-mocking-and-stubbing-just-arent-enough/

Comment: That said, it sounds more like hyperbole than anything else: mocking/stubbing means you're working on *your* code, e.g., you'd mock/stub a service call to return the data you expect. Their version of this stands up a real server and lets you define the response (an integration test, e.g., your code will be making an actual HTTP call). This isn't a unit test, this is an integration test--which may or may not be what you want. But it might save you some effort (with the caveat that other tools can do this too).

Comment: Thank you Dave Newton, I did have a look at some of the docs and at some of the classes on their Github repo, for the beginner like me it still quite confusing:)

Comment: Thank you I think I start understanding it now a bit better, they say on their website that they are using it for unit testing http://codesv.io/ do you think they mean integration tests by that?

Comment: I have no way of knowing what *they* mean--but if code is making an actual HTTP call then it's an integration test because you're reaching across application boundaries.

Comment: I am happy to up-vote your second comment as an answer to my question if you wish to post it as such, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accept the second comment as an answer to my question.

Mock will be used for a Unit Test.

Simulating virtual service will be used for Integration Testing because it is acting as a server and an actual HTTP calls are being made.